# Translate curl to http request in android app

Tags: javascript, android, http, curl

I am developing an android app with ionic 2 and I need to send data to a redcap server (https://www.project-redcap.org/, example code to interact with redcap using the provided api http://redcap-tools.github.io/projects/)

I tried to translate from curl commands to http post requests to use in the app and have so far been unsuccesful. For example, I translated the following curl that executes correctly

```
DATA="token=MY_TOKEN&content=project&format=csv&returnFormat=json"
CURL=`which curl`
$CURL -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
      -H "Accept: application/json" \
      -X POST \
      -d $DATA \
      MY_URL
```

into

```
this.packet = { token:        MY_TOKEN,
                content:      'project',
                format:       'json',
                returnFormat: 'json',
                type:         'flat',
                data:         'null',
          };
this.headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'});
this.http.post(this.apiurl, JSON.stringify(this.packet {headers:this.headers}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('success')
  console.log(data);
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log("Oooops!");
  });
```

that returns on the error branch.

Trying to send data did not work either. Translating the curl

```
DATA="token=MY_TOKEN&content=record&format=json&type=flat&overwriteBehavior=normal&data=[{"id":"id1","id_complete":"0","name":"myname", "demo_complete":"0"}]&returnContent=count&returnFormat=json"
CURL=`which curl`
$CURL -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
      -H "Accept: application/json" \
      -X POST \
      -d $DATA \
      MY_URL
```

into

```
 this.packet = { token:        MY_TOKEN,
                 content:      'record',
                 format:       'json',
                 returnFormat: 'json',
                 type:         'flat',
                 data:         [{"id":"id1","id_complete":"0","name":"myname", "demo_complete":"0"}],
          };
this.headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'});
this.http.post(this.apiurl, JSON.stringify(this.packet {headers:this.headers}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('success')
  console.log(data);
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log("Oooops!");
  });
```

I am at beginner level when it comes to the http calls, so I am quite sure it is a silly mistake on my part. Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.